# Series similar to harmonic function

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}\frac{1}{n}}$ converges?

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient $(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}$ changes sign at $n = m^2$ for integers $m$. So you are effectively summing an alternating series here. If you can show that the absolute value of the sum of
all terms in a "block" where $(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}$ is of the same sign decreases to zero as the series progresses, then the alternating series test will apply.

A variant on this approach which might be easier: Show that replacing $n$ by $m^2$ results in a series which can be more easily seen to converge as above by the alternating series test, then show the difference of the two series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: You would need to show the sizes of the blocks are decreasing in order to use the alternating test, which is not at all obvious.

Comment: No, you don't need that to be true (and it's not true here).

Comment: I didn't write what I meant, I've corrected it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I worded it pretty badly. I meant sizes as in "absolute values of the sums".

Comment: I just left out the "decreasing" part when I originally answered it, that's all. But they do decrease here.

Comment: I believe you, but it seems to me like this the hardest part of the proof and you conveniently left it out, so I treat this as a non-answer.

Comment: I intentionally left it out, so as not to do someone's homework for him/her. In other words, the answer was a hint, a sketch of an argument. And there are other details to worry about too.

Comment: Ok, I added another hint to make it easier. That's all I'm going to do here :)